# In ExtJS4, why are parameters loggable but not programmatically accessible?

Tags: javascript, extjs4, sencha-architect

I'm using Sencha Architect 2 to create an application. I've run into an issue a few different times while writing event handlers where I cannot access data.

Specifically, I am trying to write an AfterRender function to programmatically select the first item in a combobox. The combobox is populated from a JSON store, which loads fine. I'm not able to access loaded data, so I have the following code in the function to log what is available:

```js
onComboboxAfterRender: function(abstractcomponent, options) {
  // abstractcomponent.value = abstractcomponent.store.data.items[0].date;
  console.log(abstractcomponent);
  console.log(abstractcomponent.store);
  console.log(abstractcomponent.store.data);
  console.log(abstractcomponent.store.data.items);
  console.log(abstractcomponent.store.data.items[0]);
}
```

The following is the javascript console output:

[image: console.log output]

As can be seen, in `abstractcomponent.store.data`, the third item logged, items is shown to be empty. Yet if I drill in, items is an array with three entries.

Obviously I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. I would appreciate advice on how to access store data from inside the After Render handler, as well as if there's some sort of fundamental ExtJS/JavaScript/JavaScript console misconception that I have, because it makes no sense to me what is occurring.

Comment: If this is in Chrome, be aware it has "quirks" dealing with `console.log` so it may be an issue with "deferred evaluation". See if forcing an immediate conversion to a string (before passing the value to `console.log`) makes it yield the expected results.

Comment: Interesting. It is Chrome, but using Firefox / Firebug, I get the same result -- abstractcomponent.store.data when collapsed shows property items as a zero-length array, but when drilling in, the same property shows it has the expected 3 items -- which I can't programmatically access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a reference. When you outputted it to the console the store had not yet been populated.

However when you use Chrome/Firebug and expand the console it is now there and will be filled out.